# Display Control from MainWindow ontop of View

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to take a control that is created in the Mainwindow and when switching views... make its zindex topmost to display over top of the view?

I tried playing with ZIndex but had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx) is a Canvas property, so it won't work for other panel types like Grid, etc.  If you need it to appear on top, you could have the control inherit from or placed inside a [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx).

Alternatively, if you add it at the very bottom of the main window's XAML, then it should render on top.

Comment: Ah, forgot I could add to the bottom. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to tried DockPanel.

```
 <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">

 <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
               Background="OliveDrab"
               Foreground="Cornsilk"
               FontFamily="Veranda"
               FontSize="20"
               TextAlignment="Center">
 </DockPanel>
```